# При выводе текста с помощью метода nextLine файл не выводится полностью

Tags: java

Задача: надо найти в текстовом файле определённые слова. Программа работает на маленьком созданном файле, в нужном же(большой файл по объёму) перестаёт. Решила вывести необходимый файл в консоль, чтобы посмотреть, всё ли вообще окей. В итоге, файл выводится только наполовину, вторая часть есть, до неё выводятся непонятные цифры "62", откуда это и почему - без понятия. 
Приведённый код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file =new File("src/2016_11_02_01.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(fr);
        int i=1;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("Палец_L")) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            i++;
        }
        fr.close();
   }
}
```

Результат: Первая половина файла куда-то исчезает

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему так происходит и как это предотвратить.

Файл:

Comment: А где i объявлено и инициализировано? Это реальный код?

Comment: @MBo исправила, спасибо
да, реальный, просто копировала фрагментами
проблема вроде бы не в этом

Comment: @Vqq50 можно текст файла?

Comment: @Vladimir конечно, подскажите пожалуйста, тут возможно скинуть его файлом?

Comment: @Vqq50 через https://pastebin.com/ проще всего

Comment: @Vladimir  давайте так)) https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GcTL/acEBN3Fdc

Comment: @Vqq50 давайте продолжим в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78390/nextline----

Comment: @Vqq50 переменная line не инициализирована. У меня данный код правильно отрабатывает

Comment: @Vladimir Да, действительно, у меня сейчас тоже всё хорошо, хотя мне казалось, что я инициализировала:(
Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная line не инициализирована.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File ("src/2016_11_02_01.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader (file);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (fr);
        int i = 1;
        String line; //изменение здесь 
        while (sc.hasNextLine ()) {
            line = sc.nextLine ();
            if (line.contains ("Палец_L")) {
                System.out.println (i);
            }
            i++;
        }
        fr.close ();
    }
}
```

После ее инициализации выводит номера строк с входящим в нее словом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Касетельно числа 62, из-за большого объема вывод в консоль переполняется и часть текста отрезается.

Comment: помогли, спасибо!